# SQL convert yyyymmdd to timestamp in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, timestamp, google-bigquery

I'm attempting to convert a string to a timestamp within SQL. The question is really quite simple, how can I convert this string into a timestamp that starts at midnight on that day?

Within my database I also have a field stored in `timestamp_micros` either one of these could work and I think converting the micros to a timestamp would be easier than the string.

For example
`20170118 => timestamp`

Query:

```
WITH allTables as (
  SELECT
      event.date as date,
      count(*) as totalSessions,
      count(DISTINCT user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id) as uniqueUsers
  FROM `namehiddenonlyhere.*`
  CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
  WHERE
      event.name = 'session_start'
  AND 
      event.date <= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
  AND
      event.date >= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY))
  GROUP BY event.date

  UNION ALL 
  SELECT
      event.date as date,
      count(*) as totalSessions,
      count(DISTINCT user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id) as uniqueUsers
  FROM `namehiddenonlyhere.*`
  CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
  WHERE
      event.name = 'session_start'
  AND 
      event.date <= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
  AND
      event.date >= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY))
  GROUP BY event.date
) SELECT 'all apps' as target, date as datapoint_time, totalSessions datapoint_value FROM allTables;
```

Comment: Doesn't the `STR_TO_DATE()` function do what you want?

Comment: The MySQL documentation has a page listing all the functions related to dates and times. Surely you could have found the answer there. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: @Barmar Surely I wouldn't be asking if I hadn't googled this already and found no results.

Comment: Which database are you actually using, MySQL or BigQuery?  Did you add the MySQL tag to get more views?

Comment: I'm using Bigquery SQL. Added mysql by habit.

Comment: All the date/time functions are listed on https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql. It doesn't look like there's anything analogous to `STR_TO_DATE`, so you'll need to use substring and concatenation to convert it to the date format that SQL understands.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not using legacy SQL. Any more insight as to how I can go about doing this? I'm very new to "advanced" sql.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `PARSE_DATE` or `PARSE_TIMESTAMP` (the format string will be the same) to get a date or a timestamp. For example:

```
SELECT
  d,
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', d) AS date,
  PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', d) AS timestamp
FROM UNNEST(['20170117', '20161231']) AS d;
```

You can read more about the format strings in the documentation. There are sections for [date](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#supported-format-elements-for-date) and for [timestamp](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#supported-format-elements-for-timestamp), which apply to `PARSE_DATE` and `PARSE_TIMESTAMP` respectively.

Edit: from your updated question, you could change your query to something like this:

```
WITH allTables as (
  SELECT
      event.date as date,
      count(*) as totalSessions,
      count(DISTINCT user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id) as uniqueUsers
  FROM `namehiddenonlyhere.*`
  CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
  WHERE
      event.name = 'session_start'
  AND 
      event.date <= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
  AND
      event.date >= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY))
  GROUP BY event.date

  UNION ALL 
  SELECT
      event.date as date,
      count(*) as totalSessions,
      count(DISTINCT user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id) as uniqueUsers
  FROM `namehiddenonlyhere.*`
  CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
  WHERE
      event.name = 'session_start'
  AND 
      event.date <= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
  AND
      event.date >= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY))
  GROUP BY event.date
) SELECT 'all apps' as target, PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date) as datapoint_time, totalSessions datapoint_value FROM allTables;
```

The only modification I made was to change:

```
date AS datapoint_time
```

to:

```
PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date) as datapoint_time
```

Comment: That does seem to work but only partially. How would I implement it into an already existing `SELECT ... FROM` query?

Comment: Just pass in the name of the column from your table rather than `d`. In the example above, I used `FROM UNNEST(...)` to simulate having a table with two rows. Maybe you could provide the query you are trying to run (as part of your question above)?

Comment: I edited my answer. You just need to use `PARSE_DATE` in the select list at the end.

Comment: That seems to work but it's outputting `2017-01-18`, I need it to be in a unix timestamp format.

Comment: Maybe just switch `PARSE_DATE` with `PARSE_TIMESTAMP`? That might give you the format that you want.

Comment: Ended up using this: `UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', date))`

Answer (score -2):

Did you try to use this expression?

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'20170118')
```

Comment: Not provided by BigQuery.