# What's the best way to convert a string to a date in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-date-functions

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
SELECT DATE(
  CAST(SUBSTR('20191024',1,4) AS INT64),
  CAST(SUBSTR('20191024',5,2) AS INT64),
  CAST(SUBSTR('20191024',7,2) AS INT64)
  );
```

Are there better ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this [related question about INT to DATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54791436/big-query-convert-int-to-date), the answer is to use [`PARSE_DATE()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date) like this:

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d','20191024');
```

Here's the meaning of the [formatting string](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#supported-format-elements-for-date):

1. `%Y`    The year with century as a decimal number.
2. `%m`    The month as a decimal number (01-12).
3. `%d`    The day of the month as a decimal number (01-31).

P.S. After I typed all this up, I found this other item: [SQL convert yyyymmdd to timestamp in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724089/sql-convert-yyyymmdd-to-timestamp-in-bigquery) but there's so much unrelated code in the Q&A.